# Haskell unwrap data

Tags: haskell, types, unwrap

If you have a data type

```
data Something = foo Integer 
               | bar Bool
```

Is there anyway I define "getters" that unwrap the Something type to get just the Integer or Bool? Right now it would be like (foo Integer) and (bar Bool). I just want the Integer or Boolean values.

Comment: You can write `data Something = Foo { getInteger :: Integer } | Bar { getBool :: Bool }` and get the functions `getInteger :: Something -> Integer` and `getBool :: Something -> Bool` for free (but they will fail horribly if you give them the wrong input).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, firstly you have a typo: data constructors must be uppercase:

```
data Something = Foo Integer
               | Bar Bool
```

What you are asking for is exactly what pattern matching is for. If you have a `Something` value called `s`:

```
case s of
  Foo f -> ... -- f is of type Integer in this "block"
  Bar b -> ... -- b is of type Bool in this "block"
```

This is how you generally approach this problem, because any kind of getter on this sort of data type will throw an error if it is constructed with the "wrong" constructor, and this allows you to handle that case. You *can* make a safe getter with something like `Maybe`, but a lot of times this will end up involving more boilerplate anyway.